# Is it unsafe to store private keys on JavaScript strings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection, cryptography, v8

Cryptographic applications need extreme caution when dealing with private keys. They often, for example, leave those encrypted on disk as long as possible. When needed, they decrypt a key, do what is required, and then completely erase it from memory (by cleaning buffers).

On JavaScript, buffers can, too, be used for private keys, but strings are, in general, more convenient. Storing private keys on strings could be a bad idea, because you can't actively erase strings from memory, you must wait for a garbage collection. Moreover, all it takes is a single memory leak for your private key to remain uncollected; and then there is string interning.

Am I being overcautious and, with enough caution, it is safe to use strings to store private keys, or am I right and it is a terrible idea overall?

Comment: What's the context here? Where is your JavaScript code running? Node?

Comment: @Pointy we're designing a library for signing crypto-currency transactions (with ECDSA). It could be used on Node.js, on web-sites, on Electron apps, it isn't really a single context. We're deciding whether it is a good idea to use strings instead of buffers for private key arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In the node.js part, it's safer.

In the browser javascript, it's VERY UNSAFE. Users can easily log the contents of variables in the browser javascript with Chrome's or Firefox's console.

Comment: About the browser case: What exactly is the issue here? Private keys should be specific to a user. If a user can access their own key, I see no reason to change it. Can you give some scenario where this is not the case? How can this be exploited from a third party or attacker?

Comment: @skiilaa is it really safe to have the private key on memory like that? Wouldn't any running app be able to spy that memory?

Comment: @MaiaVictor yes, but if you store it in a file, an app would be able to open the file, etc.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I think he means something like a Twitter API key or something.

Comment: @skiilaa OK, but that would be a secret key not a private key as in public-private key pair.

Comment: @skiilaa hmm okay then.